# iOS In-App Purchase works in sandbox, but was rejected by apple

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I've just got my app rejected on the Apple App Store because my In-App apparently crashes on the "App Store" version.

Unfortunately , I have no way of recreating this state as i can only test the sandbox environment (which works flawlessly), but apparently on Apple's side it doesn't work, and again - I have no way to test or recreate the problem.

Do you have any idea what could be done in this situation?

Shai.

Comment: Did Apple provide any more details or a crash report? If you got a crash report, you should be able to symbolise it in Xcode and see what is going on in your code

Comment: I tried symbolizing the attached crash log, and we also got "steps for reproducing", but we can't reproduce it since they test in actual production mode and we test in sandbox mode. also symbolizing it didn't really generate anything useful, unless i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Well symbolising it should give you a stack trace so you can use the debugger on that build to find out which bit is crashing. Just to add, make sure you are testing on a non-Jailbroken device when using a device in Sandbox. Also ensure you've done everything mentioned in the Technical Notes: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: We are aware of the jailbroken part, but as i said, everything was tested and working on our Sandbox, so it should work exactly the same on the production environment unless they didn't approve our in-app item before. Could you point me to some good resource on symoblising and how to read the crash log correctly ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi , were you able to resolve this issue ?  I am facing the same problem and have no clue what the problem is.  Also I did not get any crash report from the review team. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcode should symbolicate the crash log for you. you might want to try copying the crash log to your desktop - sometimes spotlight (which is used in the process) doesn't pick it up. you're trying to view the crash log on a mac which has the archived app you submitted, right?

if you're still not getting a meaningful stack trace, then there are scripts around that might help: [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

are there any other differences between your adhoc build you've been testing with and the release build you submit to apple? might a good idea to clone your release config and just change the code signing to adhoc.